# Load space separated text file into MariaDB database table

Tags: csv, text, mariadb, load, space

I have a text file that has the field headers on the first line, and the following lines are space separated fields. The spacing between each field is different. There are 45 fields. Specifically, this is an [eBird dataset](https://ebird.org/science/download-ebird-data-products). I want to load this text file into a newly created table within a database I created, so that each header is the field header in the database and each line below the headers are records. Here is a small example of the files format:

```
Header1    Header2          Header3   Header4
082739     United States    US-CA-01  1
```

I haven't tried anything yet, because I want to know what to do before I load this data into a table. I have this command prepared:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <file_path> INTO TABLE <table_name> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';
```

Will this command populate the table so that each field corresponds to each header, or do I need to tell the command how many spaces there are between each field? Will the command know that each line is terminated by a newline if not told?

Comment: Looks like the data isn't in a proper CSV-style format as it uses spaces for both separators as well as the values in the data. This might make it hard to insert it cleanly into a database without processing the data first.

Comment: I see. I did not think about processing it. I guess I can start looking into processing it, then. I appreciate the response, Mark!

Comment: Offhand, it looks like each column has a pre-determined number of characters.  `LOAD DATA` does not have an option for such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's [an R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/auk/versions/0.4.0) for filtering and processing the EBD dataset. Using R you should be able to process the data into a more manageable format for insertion into MariaDB.

For example, you can separate the fields with commas to generate CSV-formatted data that can be readily ingested by MariaDB.

Comment: I did not know this was a thing! It looks like what I need exactly! It cleans and filters the dataset! Thanks, Markusjm again!